# syntax error, unexpected keyword_or scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, syntax-error, mongoid4

I'm running `Feed.history` but It's raising the error above at the title because of the `scope` line I use in `Feed` model:

`scope :history, -> { or({:end.ne => nil}, {:end.lt => Time.current}) }`

what and why?!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
scope :history, where('$or' => [{:end.ne => nil}, {:end.lt => Time.current}])
```